# Codelite 17.0.0 occurs "process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, makedir Debug, ...) failed."

Tags: codelite

I am just learning C++ via Codelite, which was updated on 01/11. After updating to the latest version, 17.0.0, I get the error

> process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, makedir Debug, ...) failed.
>
> mingw32-make[1]: *** [AssignmentOperator.mk:90: Debug/.d] Error 2,
>
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2

when I run a simple code.

> #include <iostream>
> int main(){
> std::cout<<"Hello"<<std::endl;
> return 0;
> }

and get nothing in the terminal window.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks a lot.

I guess the probrem occured since the updating of Codelite, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a an old relic that was not handled properly during upgrade.

This can be fixed in 2 ways:

1. Update the `mkdir` command as defined by your compiler setup:

- Go to `Settings -> build settings` and select your compiler from the list
- Select the `Tools` tab
- Select the last entry at the bottom `mkdir`

Replace the content with the `mkdir` that comes with CodeLite, for example, if you have installed CodeLite under `C:\Program Files\CodeLite` (the default path), set it to

```
"C:/Program Files/CodeLite/mkdir.exe" -p
```

Notice the double quotes around the command itself

2. Change the makefile generator used

- Right click on your project and open the project settings
- In the `General` tab, under the `Makefile Generator` change the selection from `Default` -> `CodeLite Makefile Generator`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac OS 13.1,  and codelite 17.0.0,  and when I 'clean', build completed successfully. But when I run its show 'make: ***[All] Error 2.
What happened? just new to learn C++

Comment: === build completed successfully (0 errors, 0 warnings) ===                                       
 then rebuild shows:make: *** [All] Error 2

Comment: I'm also new to learn c++, so I cannot well understand. I guess the problem is caused by the section of your workspace or project. Maybe following a good C++ guide video (on Youtube or somewhere providing such sources) can help you.

Comment: OK 谢谢！ i did not know how i fixed it .  yes, i went back and watched the video for setting codelite for C++. And later suddenly it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Codelite 17 in windows.

Solution:
In Settings - Build - Tools under Makedir select the Path of mkdir.exe within in the Codelite folder (surrounded by " -quotes).

Although context help says to leave it empty in order to use the OS' own mkdir, Windows' mkdir is quite different to the mkdir of other *ix-like OS.

Furthermore for me it was necessary to explicitly add  -p
There is a hint in Codelite's change dokumentation in the recent monthly build 17.1 that it solves this problem as a bugfix.